# datamaps - dashed animated arc

Tags: d3.js, datamaps

Help,

I'm using datamaps to create a world map and I have solid line arcs going from point to point. They're animated so they get drawn on page. However try as I might I can't find a way to make the arcs dashed so that the animation appears like the dashed line is moving in a direction from point to point. I can't find an example of this anyway, I want to give the illusion of movement, of data flowing continuously from one point to another along an arc. Is this even possible in datamaps? Are there examples out there? I must be googling the wrong thing as I'm coming up short on answers.

Comment: Having a hard time visualizing how a dashed line conveys the `illusion of movement`.  Can you draw what you are after and update your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this feature using CSS animations.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500).attr("height", 400);

var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, 700]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([10, 290]);

var data = d3.range(50).map(function() {
  return Math.random() * 10
})
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("cardinal")
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return x(i);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d);
  });

var path = svg.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data));
```

```css
 #line {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 20px 0;
   height: 300px;
   background: #eee;
 }
 
 path {
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 1;
   fill: none;
   stroke-dasharray: 10;
   animation: dash 5s linear infinite;
   animation-direction: reverse;
 }
 
 @keyframes dash {
   to {
     stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
   }
 }
 
 button {
   margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```